# Friedberg's definition of a Vector space

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm reading Linear Algebra by Friedberg, Insel, and Spence. They define a vector space in chapter 1. Among the points they use to characterize vector spaces is

> $a(bx)=b(ax)$ [where $a$ and $b$ are arbitrary real scalars and $x$ is in the vector space]

How does this impose a constraint upon $x$? Is it not a trivial consequence of commutativity of real multiplication? I would really appreciate an example of a collection of entities that satisfies all vector space properties except this one.

Comment: Are you sure about that? I have the book in front of me and I don't see that axiom there. The closest thing that I see there (on page 3) is that if $a$ and $b$ are scalars and $x$ is a vector, then $a(bx)=(ab)x$.

Comment: in the edition I have (4th) the axiom (VS 6) is written as $(ab)x = a(bx)$, which is different from what you wrote. If we assume this, then you're right, because of the commutativity of field multiplication, it follows $a(bx)=(ab)x=(ba)x=b(ax)$.

Comment: That looks odd. The rule I would expect to see is $a(bx) = (ab)x$. The rule you have given then follows trivially as you suggest.

Comment: I am using a pdf; it says it is the fourth edition by Prentice Hall. Maybe it is a typo?

Comment: It is possible. I was looking at the second edition.

Comment: If we let $V=\Bbb R$ define the scalar multiplication as $ax:=a-x$, then $a(bx)=a-b+x$ and $b(ax)=b-a+x$, which are in general different. This counterexample *may* be ruled out by other axioms, of course, but if $a(bx)=(ab)x$ is not among them then it *may* be possible to adjust it.

Answer (score 0):

Let's put aside the debate in the comments about a probable typo in your PDF. For a counter-example, take $F = \Bbb{Q}[X]/(f)$, where $f$ is an irreducible polynomial of degree $4$, so that $F$ is a (commutative) field that is also a $4$-dimensional vector space over $\Bbb{Q}$. Take $V$ to be the ring $M_2(\Bbb{Q})$ of $2\times 2$-matrices with entries in $\Bbb{Q}$ and pick a vector space isomorphism $\iota : F \to V$ that maps $1$ to $\pmatrix{1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1}$. Then the operation $(a, x) \mapsto \iota(a) x : F \times V \to V$, satisfies all the vector space axioms except the axiom $a(bx) = (ab)x$ (and also does not satisfy $a(bx) = b(ax)$).

Motivation: a vector space is essentially a homomorphism of rings from a field $F$ to the automorphism ring $\mathrm{Aut}(V, V)$ of an abelian group $V$. The axiom $a(bx) = (ab)x$ is the one that requires that homomorphism to preserve multiplication. We can thwart it by identifying $F$ with $\mathrm{Aut}(V, V)$ via a mapping that preserves the vector space structures but not multiplication (while still arranging for $1x = x$ to hold).

Answer (score 0):

This should be a typo. Let $F=V=\mathbb C$. Define a scalar multiplication $\otimes:F\times V\to V$ as $a\otimes v=\operatorname{Re}(a)v$, the usual multiplication of the real part of $a$ with $v$. Clearly $\otimes$ is distributive, $1\otimes v=v$ and
$$
a\otimes(b\otimes v)=\operatorname{Re}(a)\operatorname{Re}(b)v=\operatorname{Re}(b)\operatorname{Re}(a)v=b\otimes(a\otimes v),\tag{1}
$$
but both sides of $(1)$ are not equal to $(ab)\otimes v=\operatorname{Re}(ab)v$ in general.